# Position, crop and add reflections to images, web

Tags: html, css, image, position, crop

I'd like to display multiple images on my page with the following requirements :

- they all fit in height
- they are all on a single line, crop on width if necessary
- a reflection would be nice

[image: Result expected]

I had it working using `background-image`, and the following structure:

```
<!-- row images -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="cover_pictures">
        <div class="images1">
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>  </div>
</div>


<!-- row for reflections, php generated -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 hidden-phone" id="cover_reflections">
        <div class="images1">
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://myserver/reflect.php?http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://myserver/reflect.php?http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://myserver/reflect.php?http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://myserver/reflect.php?http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="images2" style="background-image: url('http://myserver/reflect.php?http://i.imgur.com/OEy0D1X.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS :

```
#cover_pictures .images1 {
    height:350px;
}

#cover_reflections .images1 {
    height:100px;
}

.images1 {
    width:100%;
}

.images2 {
    /* top for reflections, doesnt matter for pictures*/
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto 100%;

    float:left;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px 0%;
}
```

Using this JS to resize `.images2` divs :

```
var l = dataJson.length; // number of images
var margTot = 5; // 5% of the space for margins

$(".images2").css("margin-left",  margTot / 2 / l + "%");
$(".images2").css("margin-right", margTot / 2 / l + "%");
$(".images2").css("width", (100 - margTot)/l + "%");
```

The issue is : loading reflections from PHP is super slow, generates too big images, so I want to use Reflection.js. This script only works on `<img />`, not with `background-image`, but I can't seem to make the same layout with `<img />` elements. Images are distorted, if not they only fit in width, etc etc.

I am not an expert in html/css so it may seem easy for some of you, but please be sure that any answer would be greatly appreciated ! And if you have need more details ask freely I may have forgot some.

If I can make it work easily I plan to release it on GitHub as a jQuery plugin.

EDIT: the list of images is populated with a JSON API, giving me URLs and sizes of images. I can't resize the images on the server because the number of images on a webpage varies.

EDIT: to future readers : I wanted to reward both great answers on this question so I did the following

- I granted the bounty to Troy Alfrod for his very detailled and good looking answer
- I validated the solution of Vals for its simplicity of set up

For my own scenario I decided to go with the easiest answer for now because of a very short delay to implement and test. Here is what I did :

- both `#cover_pictures > .images2` and `#cover_reflections > .images2` contain the same divs with identical `background-image`, and same style (no more `reflect.php`)
- added `transform: scaleY(-1);` (and equivalents for other browsers) to  `#cover_reflections > .images2`
- constrained the size of `#cover_reflections` to `100px`
- added the `.mask` div Vals suggested.

It works very well, except in IE7-8 because it doesn't support `background-size` property. So I added a backend in php to send every image at the correct height (with cache support, etc). That wasn't part of the plan but I had to. The height required is retrieved as such `var height = $('#cover_pictures .images1').height();`

Hope it'll help someone else !!

I'll publish here the link to the jQuery plug-in when set up.

Comment: Why don't you resize your images?

Comment: reflection => transform: scaleY(-1); and then some opacity with a gradient... I just found: http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-add-reflection-effect-on-images-using-css.html

Comment: Resizing images how ? On the server ? Not possible, the number of images varies. On the webpage ? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've read I can't use this technique with background-image styled divs because the gradient would replace the image. Maybe I'm wrong. But I think doing the reflection with Reflection.js would be the best solution, if I can do the same layout with img elements

Comment: https://www.webkit.org/blog/182/css-reflections/ would be the easiest way, but be aware that that hasn't been standardised, and I would be surprised to see it turn up in any other browsers than Webkit based ones. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-reflections reckons we are on about 49.57% of users with this ability though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a demo for you, with a simplified layout, but I think that the idea is ok:

the HTML is:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="cover_pictures">
    <div class="images1">
        <div class="images2" id="img1"></div>
        <div class="images2" id="img2"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="cover_reflections">
    <div class="ref1">
        <div class="ref2" id="img1"></div>
        <div class="ref2" id="img2"></div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>  </div>
</div>
```

Not very much different from whar¡t you already had.

I have added a mask div in the row of the reflections, to make the shadowed effect.

The CSS is

```
#cover_pictures .images1 {
    height:350px;
}
#cover_reflections .ref1 {
    height:100px;
}
.images1, .ref1 {
    width:100%;
}
#img1 {
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
}
#img2 {
    width: 250px;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/250/300');
}
.images2, .ref2 {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px 0%;
}
.images2 {    
    background-position:center top;
    background-size:auto 100%;
}
.ref2 {
    background-position:center bottom;
}
#cover_reflections .ref1 {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-0.9);
} 
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, center bottom, center top, color-stop(0.1, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), color-stop(0.95, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)));
}
```

It is pretty much the same; I have changed the background images from the HTML to the CSS.

The key is the scaleY negative for the reflections (following bwoebi idea). I put a little less than 1, to look more like a reflection, but it's up to you.

Some properties have to change for this to work ok, for instance the position has to be bottom.

And finally, use the mask div scaled to cover all the ref1 div, with a gradient going from transparent to white.

I have not included the JavaScript, and fixed the dimensions by hand, but you can do that as you already did.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/BBx4q/embedded/result/)

Editing: added transparency and some bluriness (only available in webkit). Added one div to check the transparency.

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/BBx4q/1/embedded/result/)

the changes are here

```
#cover_reflections .ref1 {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    opacity: 0.65;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

I think that the problem that you say caused by a dimension change is related to the previous scaleY(-0.9),  I think that now is behaving ok. About it being responsive, it's just that I haven't included your Javascript in my code, since I don't think this is the point, but it should work ok without problems

Comment: this solution works well but if I understand well it relies on saving the image width in the div style. So using this I won't be able have a responsive layout, will I ?

Comment: oh and modifying the height of `#cover_pictures .images` the reflection isn't correct anymore, but I guess than can be easily fixed

Comment: and the background of the website may have a texture, so this is not real transparency :/

Comment: The responsive issue is not a problem; I just left it out of the demo, but it will work ok as you had it. The height, as you already said, can be easily fixed. The transparency is a bigger issue. It can be done in older browser via opacity, but then it is all or nothing (can not be gradal). Doing it properly means using filters, and this won't work in older browsers ...

Comment: web dev is so frustrating for this ! but you transparency test is a very nice start!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer this alternative solution, using only CSS and only one set of images:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="cover_pictures">
        <div class="images">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cover_pictures { font-size: 0; }
.images { position: relative; }
.images > .img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 350px; width: 50px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.images > .img, .images > .img:after {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.images > .img:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -58px;

    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv;
    filter: flipv;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 40px 60px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 40px 60px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 40px 60px #fff;
}

.images > .img:nth-child(1), .images > .img:nth-child(1):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/110/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(2), .images > .img:nth-child(2):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/120/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(3), .images > .img:nth-child(3):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/130/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(4), .images > .img:nth-child(4):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/145/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(5), .images > .img:nth-child(5):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/150/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(6), .images > .img:nth-child(6):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/160/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(7), .images > .img:nth-child(7):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/170/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(8), .images > .img:nth-child(8):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/180/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(9), .images > .img:nth-child(9):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/195/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(10), .images > .img:nth-child(10):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/205/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(11), .images > .img:nth-child(11):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/210/350);
}
.images > .img:nth-child(12), .images > .img:nth-child(12):after { 
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/240/350);
}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

To explain, the CSS works by injecting an `:after` pseudo-element after each one of the images. The images themselves are `clip`ped to only display in the correct size, as are the `:after` versions.

The `:after` element then contains exactly the same image as its parent, but is vertically-flipped using CSS, so that only the bottom `60px` shows. The fade effect is then created by using an offset `box-shadow` with a `40px` dispersion, radiating upwards.

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/TyhRM/) for you to play with.

Comment: I must admit this solution is super sexy ! But in the fiddle when i resize the height of the html preview the images move but not the reflections. And I think their is simply no way of having it working in IE7-IE8?

Comment: Made an update to the Fiddle that fixes the positioning. I'll work on the IE bit, as well.

Comment: A bit of testing in IE10 set to different modes seems to indicate that it will work in IE7/8. I don't actually have an environment to test those browsers with for real, though - so I'm not sure. I believe as long as they're set to Standards mode it should work. Quirks mode may even work - but not sure.

Comment: I tested on IE9 it seems okay but I can't test other versions. It is very nice !

Comment: Thanks! Glad you like it. :) If you're using it, please consider marking it as the correct answer, by clicking the green checkbox beside it. :)

Comment: well I'm a bit short on time to implement it correctly and perform full testing, so I use a modified version of Vars' answer. But since yours is a better approach i gave you the bounty. For more details I edited my question

Answer (score -1):

You can grab the src of every img tag and add it as background image with jQuery. Then Reflection.js will work.

Just be sure to get the images in a hidden div.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood it. You mean Reflection.js will work with hidden divs ? Could you edit and add a example of the html content ?